# Does ZF prove that topological groups are completely regular?

Tags: topological-groups, axiom-of-choice, set-theory, lo.logic

Let $\mathbf{G} = \langle G,\cdot,\mathcal{T}\;\rangle$ be a topological group. Let $\mathbf{e}$ be the identity element of $\langle G,\cdot \rangle$.
Assume $\{\mathbf{e}\}$ is closed in $\langle G,\cal{T}\;\rangle$. Then, I have managed to convince myself that:

1. ZF proves that $\langle G,\cal{T}\;\rangle$ is regular Haudorff.
2. ZF + (Dependent Choice) proves that $\langle G,\cal{T}\;\rangle$ is completely regular.

My questions are:

1. Are those right?
2. Does ZF prove that $\langle G,\cal{T}\;\rangle$ is completely regular?
3. If no to question 2, does assuming one or more of following suffice for ZF to conclude that $\langle G,\cal{T}\,\rangle$ is completely regular?

   1. $\mathbf{G}$ is [two-sided complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Examples)
   2. $\langle G,\cdot \rangle$ is abelian
   3. Countable Choice

Comment: I think I can confirm that ZF+DC proves that a Hausdorff topological group is completely regular. Dependent choice appears in Urysohn's proof that a uniform space is completely regular, and I do not see how to remove it. In fact, the whole question hangs on the following: does ZF prove that a uniform space is completely regular? My instinct tells me that the answer is negative, even with Countable choice. Of course, my instincts are often wrong.

Comment: I'll go on a limb here and claim that intuitionistic logic with Dependent Choice proves every Hausdorff group to be regular.

Comment: Ricky just posted a new version of this question in terms of proximities - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73952/does-zf-prove-that-proximity-spaces-are-completely-regular

Comment: Would it be interesting to come up with a model of ZF and a topological group there that is not completely regular.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the proof I gave, But as I checked, it didn't use full AC, but as [Asaf](https://mathoverflow.net/users/7206/asaf-karagila) mentioned in a comment it uses DC. The following theorem is due to [Pontrjagin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lev_Pontryagin). See [Book by Montgomery and Zippin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0882751697)(Page 29).
I will give a sketch of proof.

**Note**: Maybe it's needed to add some separation axiom to the following theorem. please edit it, if needed.

#### Theorem: Every $T_{0}$ topological group is completely regular.

*Proof.*
It's enough to prove that a given topological group $(G,*)$ is completely regular at $e$. Let $F$ be a closed set not containing $e$. Put $O=F^{c}$. Choose symmetric open neighborhoods  of $e$, $U_{n}$ By continuity of $*$, such that $U_{0}=O$(w.l.o.g assume $O$ is symmetric) $U_{n+1}^2 \subseteq U_{n} \cap O ~~~~n=0,1,2...$.

Now for rational numbers of the form $r=\frac{k}{2^n}~~k \in \{1,2,3,...2^n \},~~ n \in \{0,1,2,...\}$ inductively define open neighborhood $V_{r}$ of $e$ such that:

*1)* $V_{\frac{1}{2^n}}=U_{n}~~~~~\forall n$

*2)* $V_{\frac{2k}{2^{n+1}}}=V_{\frac{k}{2^n}}$

*3)* $V_{\frac{2k+1}{2^{n+1}}}=V_{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}V_{\frac{k}{2^n}}$

The definition does not depend to the representation of $r$ and the family $V_{r}$ has the following properties:

*4)* $V_{\frac{1}{2^n}}V_{\frac{m}{2^{n}}} \subseteq V_{\frac{m+1}{2^n}}~~~~~~~~~m+1 \leq 2^n$

*5)* $V_{r} \subseteq V_{s}~~~~~$if $~r <s<1$
Now define the function $f:G \longrightarrow [0, 1]$ as follows:

$f(x)=0~$ if $x \in \bigcap \limits_{r} V_{r}$

$f(x)=1$ if $~~x \notin V_{1}$, and in other cases define:

$f(x)= \sup \{r \leq 1 : x \notin V_{r}\}$

#### Claim: $f$ is as required.

Comment: Defining a sequence by induction is the quintessential use of dependent choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you. I don't know much about AC and related things, Is it an answer of question 2.

Comment: No, it just answers (part of) question 1.

Comment: I am not sure about the necessity of $T_{0}$, maybe closed-ness of $\{e\}$ is sufficient.

Comment: About" maybe closedness of $\{e\}$ is sufficient": In a topological group, if $\{e\}$ is closed, then, by homogeneity, all singletons are closed, and so the topology satisfies $T_1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass since $T_{1} \longrightarrow T_{0}$, so if my answer uses only DC, then it answers question2.

Comment: Although $T_1$ is stronger than $T_0$ in general, they're equivalent in topological groups.

Comment: Rahman. M: no, it doesn't answer question 2. Question 2 reads, "Does ZF prove that $\langle G, \mathcal{T} \rangle$ is completely regular?" Since ZF does not prove ZF + DC (i.e., since DC is not provable in ZF), this answer does not address question 2. It only addresses part 2 of question 1 ("Are those right?", with part 2 asserting "ZF + (Dependent Choice) proves that $\langle G, \mathcal{T} \rangle$ is completely regular".

Comment: @ToddTrimble oh,I meant $ZF+DC$ by 2! It was my fault. I understand what happened. Both of us mean one thing!!sorry!